# Taxes code check, what is wrong, what's the difference?

Tags: c#, compare

please help me with the following code. The code itself is from UriOnlineJudge(https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1051), but after many hours spent trying to figure out the problem i had to resolve to this site.
First one is this:

```
            double sal = 0.0, t8 = 0.0, t18 = 0.0, t28 = 0.0;
            sal = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(sal <= 2000.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Isento");
            }else if( 2000.0 < sal && sal <= 3000.0)
            {
                t8 = ((sal - 2000.00) * 0.08);
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:F2}", t8));
            } else if (3000.0 < sal && sal <= 4500.0)
            {
                t18 = ((sal - 3000.00) * 0.18 + 1000.00 * 0.08);
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:F2}", t18));
            }
            else
            {
                t28 = ((sal - 4500.00) * 0.28 + 1500.00 * 0.18 + 1000.00 * 0.08);
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:F2}", t28));
            }
           Console.ReadLine();
```

After some hours of thinking i decided to make it "cleaner"(less lines) and re-did it like that, and amazingly it worked, but i still didnt understand why is that, to me they are the same
the second one is this:

```
    double sal = 0.0, t8 = 0.0, t18 = 0.0, t28 = 0.0;
            sal = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(sal <= 2000.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Isento");
            }else if( 2000.0 < sal && sal <= 3000.0)
            {
                sal = sal - 2000.0;
                t8 = sal * 8.0 / 100.0;
                t8 = sal + t8;
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", t8));
            } else if (3000.0 < sal && sal <= 4500.0)
            {
                sal = sal - 3000.0;
                t8 = 1000.0 * 8.0 / 100.0;
                t18 = sal;
                t18 = t18 * 18.0 / 100.0;
                t18 = t18 + t8;
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", t18));
            }
            else
            {
                sal = sal - 4500.0;
                t8 = 1000.0 * 8.0 / 100.0;
                t18 = 1500.0 * 18.0 / 100.0;
                t28 = sal;
                t28 = t28 * 28.0 / 100.0;
                t28 = t28 + t18 + t8;
                Console.WriteLine("R$ " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", t28));
            }
           Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, i've been testing them back and forth and they show the SAME results, but mr. Uri's compiler keep showing me that the second code is still 5% wrong, please i beg you to help me find the error of my ways.

Comment: Well, by "cleaner" i meant less lines. I apologize for the wrong idea. 
I cant figure it out either, they seem exactly the same to me too.

Comment: Ahh ok so yours is the first one... gotcha. anyway, id make 2 methods of them both, with a return type of double, and compare them against each other given differing test input (i.e test cases)

Comment: i am not that smart of a programmer yet, maybe an example to illuminate my dim mind?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dz3D7H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with a problem like this, [write test cases](http://dotnetfiddle.net/Dz3D7H)

Assuming your code is the first block, your mistake is here

```
return (sal - 2000.00) * 0.08;
```

it should be

```
return (sal - 2000.00) + (sal - 2000.00) * 0.08;
```

because the original code is

```
sal = sal - 2000.0;
t8 = sal * 8.0 / 100.0;
// you aren't doing this step 
t8 = sal + t8;
```